# Common Lisp: Is there a version of `labels` with a type specifier?

Tags: function, types, overloading, common-lisp

Is there a Common Lisp construct that is to `labels` what `defmethod` is to `defun`? That is, I would like to use `labels` (or something similar) to define several local functions that would have the same name but differ in parameters they accept and let the compiler choose among them.

As an MWE, I would like to achieve the following functionality

```lisp
(defmethod write-first-item-type ((lst list))
  "Writes the type of the first item in lst."
  (labels ((write-single ()
             (format t "a single float"))
           (write-double ()
             (format t "a double float")))

    (format t "The first item is: ~A.~%"
        (cond ((eql (type-of (car lst)) 'single-float)
               (write-single))
              ((eql (type-of (car lst)) 'double-float)
               (write-double))
              (t
               (format t "unknown"))))))
```

with something like

```lisp
(defmethod write-first-item-type ((lst list))
  "Should write the type of the first item in lst but does not compile."
  (label-method ((write-type ((item single-float))
                   (format t "a single float"))
                 (write-type ((ifem double-float))
                   (format t "a double float")))

    (format t "The first item is: ~A.~%"
        (write-type (car lst)))))
```

Admitably, my MWE is rather silly. My actual motivation is that while cleaning up my source code I would like to put bunches of little helper functions (created with `defmethod`) into the one big function that uses them. Feel free to comment on this motivation as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See here why the initial proposal for local generic bindings were removed from CLOS:

[Issue GENERIC-FLET-POORLY-DESIGNED Writeup](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Issues/iss181_w.htm)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying that such an operator (in the form of `generic-flet`) used to exist in some implementations but was removed for reasons given in the document you link?

Comment: @DominikMokriš : yes

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a built-in functionality of that kind. However, such kind of feature is not hard to build from scratch, as long as other parts of OOP are not required (i.e., inheritance and other dispatching orders).

If you would never call `(call-next-method)` in you `method-labels` code (as you won't do in `labels` code, it is just a matter of defining a dispatch table and dispatch "methods" accordingly. To break it down, it should be a local macro that:

1. defines a local variable (`gensym`) as the dispatch table;
2. registers functions as closures together with its specialized lambda list into the dispatch table;
3. register a local "generic" function, that when called, find the function to call from the dispatch table according to the parameters supplied.

And to find the function, you may or may not need to:

1. sort the dispatch table (but if there is not `eql` specifier nor inheritance, this can be avoided)
2. write dedicated code to match against the specialized parameters for `&optional`, `&key`, and other options of the lambda list (or you can use `destructuring-bind`, but you'll need to transform the specialized lambda list into a lambda list) - there might be tools for that, but I am unaware of.

In the simplest case where the number of parameters in the lambda list is fixed, the dispatch can be as plain as a few `(e)typecase`.

Answer (score 1):

The local/global methods are for you probably a matter of namespaces.
That you don't want to pollute the current namespace with this matter.

How about to create on-the-fly small namespace/packages and use therein the "global" methods of CLOS?

It would have nearly the same effect of having local functions which are "invisible" for other functions.

```
(defpackage my-sub
  (:use :cl)
  (:export #:write-type))

(in-package :my-sub)

(defgeneric write-type (x)
  (:documentation "write type of x"))

(defmethod write-type ((x float))
  (typecase x
    (single-float "single float")
    (double-float "double float")))

(defmethod write-type ((x string))
  "string")

(defpackage my-main
  (:use :cl
        :my-sub))

(in-package :my-main)

(defmethod write-first-item-type ((lst list))
  (format nil "first item is: ~A." (my-sub:write-type (car lst))))

(write-first-item-type '("a" b c))
;; "first item is: string."

(write-first-item-type '(1.0 2 3))
;; "first item is: single float."

(write-first-item-type '(1.0d0 2 3))
;; "first item is: double float."
```

`defmethod` anyway can only dispatch for `classes` - builtin or self-made.
But you want to dispatch for `types`.

So I put example for members of class `float` (`single-float` and `double-float`) - dispatch them manually useing `typecase`.
And of built-in class `string`.

Use packaging for namespace separation.

However just manual dispatch is better in this case.

```
(defmethod write-first-item-type ((lst list))
  (labels ((write-type (x)
             (typecase x
               (single-float "single float")
               (double-float "double float")
               (string "string")
               (t "unkown"))))
     (format nil "The first item is: ~A." (write-type (car lst)))))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a reasonable way to go when cleaning up the source code.